# Open Excel from Word using FileDialog

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

What I want to do is:

- Press a button in my Microsoft Word doc it will prompt me to select a document in the file explorer.
- Select my document the relevant fields in my word doc will be populated.
- This will be populated based upon information in the document (the month) and using a `Match` function it will search for the correct row/column in the selected excel document and return the value.

I am stuck on the `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` section of my code below.

For the purpose of my document I can not enter the direct file path, the file path needs to be taken from the `FileDialog` function (or something similar).

I have also tried `GetOpenFilename`. I am unsure how to do this. My code currently opens FileDialog and lets me select a file, but I can not pass the file path onto my colNum1 line.

The error I get is *Run-time error '91'. Object variable or With Block variable not set.*

I am open to suggestions and any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub KPI_Button()
'
' KPI_Button Macro
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim strFile As String
Dim Doc As String
Dim Res As Integer
Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog

Doc = ThisDocument.Name

Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Res = dlgSaveAs.Show

colNum1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("(Month)", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I2"), 0)

ThisDocument.hoursworkedMonth.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, colNum1)

exWb.Close
Set exWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try a dialog that specifies an Excel extension as such:

```
Sub GetNames()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*", 1
If .Show = True Then
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    'this is the path you need
    MsgBox .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
    MsgBox "no valid selection"
    End If
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have entered that but instead of it physically displaying the path on screen I need it to pass the file path for the spreadsheet onto the last two sections of my above code:

   `colNum1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("(Month)", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:I2"), 0)


    ThisDocument.hoursworkedMonth.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, colNum1)`

Comment: @Krumblebee this line gives you the full path `.SelectedItems(1)` that you can apply to your function.

Comment: I want to open the file specified when I use the FIleDialog function. I do not need to see the file path to then allow me to enter it into my code. I want the file path to be passed to a line of code in my VBA. All I need to do is open my selected file using the file dialog function then the operations I have in place can be carried out on the selected file. The file selected will always be different so the file path will always change, that is why I cant enter the file path in every time. I hope I have made sense of what I am trying to do. Thanks for the help so far though.